# The width of a convex body is a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I'm studying an article by Shinzo Kakutani.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968964?origin=crossref

It states that every convex body $K$ (a compact convex set with non-empty interior) in 3-dimensional space has a circumscribed cube, i.e. a cube all of whose faces touch the body. In the proof of the theorem he defines a function $f:\mathbb{S}^2⟶\mathbb{R}$
such that for any $v\in\mathbb{S}^2$ there is a unique support hyperplane $H(K,v)$ of $K$ with outer normal vector $v.$

Let $f(v)$ be the vertical distance of these two planes $H(K,v)$ and $H(K,-v)$,
$f(v)=dist(H(K,v),H(K,-v))$
I proved that $f$ is a well-defined function, guaranteeing the existence of such planes in the definition but I can't prove that $f(v)$ is a continuous function.
How to calculate the $\lim_{w\to v}|f(w)−f(v)|$?

I know that $f$ is a width function, but I can't find this demonstration of continuity.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think the paper claims that there is a unique hyperplane normal to a given $v$. It says "*for each $P$, take two tangent hyperplanes perpendicular to $P$  ... let $f(P)$ be the vertical distance of the two planes*". However it also says that the two planes may coincide (which I don't understand)). And I don't see how to prove that $f$ is continuous either at the moment.

Comment: Because $K$ is compact, in any direction $v$ there are planes $v\cdot x = d$ such that $K$ is entirely on the opposite side of the plane from the direction $v$. The set of all such $d$ is bounded below by $v\cdot x$ for any $x \in K$, and thus has an infimum $d(v)$. The plane for $d(v)$ is tangent to $K$ and is unique, in having $K$ completely below it. However, the plane $v \cdot x = -d(-v)$ is also tangent to $K$, but has $K$ completely above it. Convexity can be used to show $d(v)$ is a continuous function of $v$, and your function is $|d(v)+d(-v)|$, which is thus also continuous.